# Independence of random variables

Tags: statistics, probability

> let U = the number of trials needed to get the first head

and

> let V = number of trials needed to get two heads in repeated tosses of a fair coin.

Are U and V independent random variables?

I would say they are dependent if

- u = number of trials before first head appears
- v = number of trials to get 2nd head after the event u has occurred

Please help me understand it!

Comment: I think that this question would be better on Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.